# centOS 7 access denied when logging on kerberized environment

Tags: centos, security, kerberos, hadoop

When I am trying to log in to one of my hadoop nodes running centos 7. I am receiving a 'access denied' error. Typically, in these situations, I login as the local admin for the box, go to /tmp and delete an old `krb5cc_xxx` file and then I am able to get back onto the system.

Now when I go to /tmp I am only seeing `krbcc` files owned by the proper users such as hdfs, kafka, hive, etc; none by my username. I am really at a loss here. How can I find which file is tied to my locked out account?

Comment: It’s unusual that deleting an old ccache file would resolve a problem like that. Are you using gssapi to log in or typing a password?  What is the error in the logs that corresponds to your login failure?

Comment: @jsbillings I am typing a password I will update the question with the logs.